# Cant copy filename%Date:/=%AM.txt - File not found

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I have a batch file that creates a logfile with the current date appended as part of the name.

```
c:\csserver\testsam.bat >> Z:\tests\hcls%Date:/=%AM.txt
```

This command executes successfully.

In the same batch file I want to copy `Z:\tests\hcls%Date:/=%AM.txt` to another location with a different name so that my taskscheduler can pick it up and email it to me as proof of execution but it does not work. I get the error message "The system cannot find the file specified" when I run the batch file.

Comment: Add the entire code of your batch file or at least the command where you copy the file.

Comment: also your actual output of `echo %date%` could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is that %date% has a space in it and you are not surrounding your filename with quotes, which is always a best practice to avoid any issues.

Using `echo` to debug your script will show you what is happening so you can find issues.  These can be removed or commented out when you have your script working.

Here is a script that demonstrates this in action:

```
echo "d:\test\foo%Date:/=%AM.txt"
echo FOO >> "d:\test\foo%Date:/=%AM.txt"
copy "d:\test\foo%Date:/=%AM.txt" "d:\test\foo%Date:/=%AM.copy.txt"
```

And the output:

```
d:\test>foo.cmd

d:\test>echo "d:\test\fooTue 12292015AM.txt"
"d:\test\fooTue 12292015AM.txt"

d:\test>echo FOO  1>>"d:\test\fooTue 12292015AM.txt"

d:\test>copy "d:\test\fooTue 12292015AM.txt" "d:\test\fooTue 12292015AM.copy.txt"
        1 file(s) copied.

d:\test>dir

 Directory of d:\test

12/29/2015  03:48 PM               144 foo.cmd
12/29/2015  03:48 PM                 6 fooTue 12292015AM.copy.txt
12/29/2015  03:48 PM                 6 fooTue 12292015AM.txt
```